# How can I read an observable without page refresh (declarative pattern)?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I am trying to set/read if a user is authenticated in my application. I have things working, but as I am learning more about RxJs, I am trying to refactor things to be more declarative.

My code samples below are 98% working. When I log in, I am seeing my logging statement in my service as expected with the correct value(s):

> console.log('setting auth status...', status); // true

However, I'm not seeing the logging in my component:

> console.log('reading isAuthenticated$ status... ', response) <-- not seeing this when logging in

If I refresh my page, I am seeing `Hello World` as expected. Since I am subscribing using the `async` pipe, I thought I would see the ui update without having to refresh.

If I log out, (click a button). I am seeing *all* logging statements as expected every time--even without refreshing.

> console.log('setting auth status...', status); // false

> console.log('reading isAuthenticated$ status... ', response) // false

This makes me think there is something wrong how I am emitting or reading `isAuthenticated$` observable.

How can I read the `isAuthenticated$` observable in my template without refreshing?

Here is my service:

```
// auth.service.ts

export class AuthService {
    private readonly baseURL = environment.baseURL;
    private isAuthenticatedSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(
        this.hasAccessToken()
    );

    isAuthenticated$ = this.isAuthenticatedSubject.asObservable();

    ...

    signInWithEmailPassword(
        emailPasswordCredentials: EmailPasswordCredentials
    ) {
        return this.httpClient
            .post<Response>(
                `${this.baseURL}/v1/auth/signin`,
                emailPasswordCredentials
            )
            .pipe(
                map((authResponse) => {
                    // set auth cookie
                    this.setAuthenticatedStatus(true);
                })
                catchError((err) => {
                    return throwError(err);
                })
            );
    }


    ...

    setAuthenticatedStatus(status: boolean): void {
        console.log('setting auth status...', status);
        this.isAuthenticatedSubject.next(status); // true|false
    }

    signOut(): void {
        this.router.navigate(['/signin']).then(() => {
            this.setAuthenticatedStatus(false);
        });
    }
}
```

Here is what my component looks like:

```
// app.component.ts

isAuthenticated$ = this.authService.isAuthenticated$.pipe(
    tap((response) =>
        console.log('reading isAuthenticated$ status... ', response)
    ),
    catchError((err) => {
        this.message = err;
        return EMPTY;
    })
);
```

Finally, here is my template:

```
<div *ngIf="isAuthenticated$ | async">Hello World!</div>
```

**EDIT**

I have a `login.component` that handles the email/password button click. It looks like this:

```
signInWithEmailPassword(form: FormGroup): void {
    if (form.invalid) {
        return;
    }

    ...
    this.authService.signInWithEmailPassword(this.form.value).subscribe({
            next: (response) => {
                this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']).then(() => {
                    // this.authService.setAuthenticatedStatus(true);  // This doesn't seem to impact anything
                });     
            },
            error: (err) => {
                this.handleHttpError(err);
            },
            complete: () => {
                //...
            },
        });
    }
```

I thought that by setting that in my `login.component` I could update that subject. It all works after I refresh the page. The nav shows...but if I just login... it's like I'm not "watching" on my `app.component` that observable or something.

**EDIT/UPDATE**

I have tried to set up a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jhshqi?file=src%2Fapp%2Frouter%2Froutes.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fauthentication%2Fauth.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) to help illustrate what I'm running into. I am not sure how to mock the auth part to return a dummy response, but hopefully this will help.

Comment: Do you subscribe to `signInWithEmailPassword` ?

Comment: I have a `login.component` where I call `this.authService.signInWithEmailPassword(this.form.value).subscribe({...`

I have updated my question to better reflect what that looks like...

Comment: I see no obvisous problem with your code snipets. Could you provide a [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Are you, by any chance, wrapping `<div *ngIf="isAuthenticated$ | async">Hello World!</div>` inside other tags, which have structural directives on them? Your described behavior would pretty much be the behavior I would expect if this div is wrapped in some other tag conditionally rendering it's content (e.g. via ngIf).

Comment: Hi @MatthieuRiegler - I was able to put together a stackblitz above. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost I want to thank everyone for their suggestions & answers. They really helped me think through things to find what I was doing wrong.

In the end, I created a [stripped-down Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3tjf8r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) of what I was trying to do. It was interesting that everything seemed to work as expected, and after several days of chasing, I decided that there was something *somewhere* in my application that was causing my trouble.

I started a new application, and everything now is working as expected.

Here is what my application looks like, hopefully this will help someone else...

Here is the `login.component`:

```
// login.component.ts

public signInWithEmailPassword(form: FormGroup): void {
    if (form.invalid) {
        return;
    }

        this.authService.signInWithEmailPassword(this.form.value).subscribe({
            next: (response: AuthResponse) => {
                this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']).then(() => {
                        //...
                    });
            },
            error: (err) => {
                console.log('err: ', err);
            },
            complete: () => {
                //...
            },
        });
    }
```

Here is my `app.component`

```
// app.component.ts

export class AppComponent {
    message: string | undefined;

    isAuthenticated$ = this.authService.isAuthenticated$.pipe(
        catchError((err) => (this.message = err))
    );

    constructor(
        private readonly authService: AuthService
    ) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Here is what my template looks like:

```
// app.template

<div>
    <app-desktop-sidebar *ngIf="isAuthenticated$ | async"></app-desktop-sidebar>

    <div>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my `auth.service`:

```
// auth.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

import { catchError, Observable, throwError, tap, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

import { EmailPasswordCredentials } from './models/email-password-credentials.model';
import { AuthResponse } from './models/auth-response.interface';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
    private readonly baseURL = environment.baseURL;
    private isLoadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    private isAuthenticatedSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(
        this.hasAccessToken()
    );

    public isLoading$ = this.isLoadingSubject.asObservable();
    public isAuthenticated$ = this.isAuthenticatedSubject.asObservable();

    constructor(
        private readonly httpClient: HttpClient,
    ) {
        //...
    }

    public signInWithEmailPassword(
        emailPasswordCredentials: EmailPasswordCredentials
    ): Observable<AuthResponse> {
        this.setLoadingStatus(true);

        return this.httpClient
            .post<AuthResponse>(
                `${this.baseURL}/v1/auth/signin`,
                emailPasswordCredentials
            )
            .pipe(
                tap((response) => {
                    ...
                    this.setLoadingStatus(false);
                    this.isAuthenticatedSubject.next(true);
                }),
                catchError((err) => {
                    this.setLoadingStatus(false);
                    return throwError(err);
                })
            );
    }

    public signOut() {
        this.isAuthenticatedSubject.next(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your problem is that you has a router like

```
  {path:'login',component:LoginComponent},
  {path:'',component: HomeComponent,children:[
    {path:'dashboard',component:DashboardComponent}
    {path:'other',component:OtherComponent}
  ]}
```

and your HomeComponent like

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

So, when you login, the authservice emit a value but the "header" it's not, so can not listen the new value

The solution is use a BehaviourSubject, not a Subject

```
export class LoginService {
  isAuthenticatedSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  isAuthenticated$ = this.isAuthenticatedSubject as Observable<boolean>;

  constructor() {}
  login(status: boolean) {
    this.isAuthenticatedSubject.next(status);
  }
}
```

See a [little stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ttznp6?file=src%2Fapp%2Flogin.service.ts)
the "dashboard" component has "login" component

Comment: Hi @Eliseo!  I have tried to include a StackBlitz to show my setup. I'm not sure how to stub in the auth part, but all of the files are there.